# How to convert Cycles to nanoseconds

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I wanted to convert Cycles based on CPU counter register values to nano seconds in Linux.

I can see Linux provides cyc_to_ns()/clocksource_cyc2ns api's for the same.

Both the api's required three arguments to be passed.

For example:

cyc_to_ns(u64 cyc, u32 mult, u32 shift);

Now I do have cyc(CPU counter register) value with me but don't have values of mult and shift.

Can anyone point me out, how should I calculate these two values (mult and shift)?

Comment: `cyc_to_ns` is [static](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/sched_clock.c?v=4.1#L91) for linux kernel implementation. How you except to use it?

Comment: I need to call this api's from one from one of my function with three required arguments. I can now have first two arguments with me but I how do I calculate third argument .i.e "shift" ?

Comment: *Where* your function will be implemented? In file `kernel/time/sched_clock.c`? `cyc_to_ns` cannot be used outside of this file.

Comment: Ok, I can see it is defined as static ,so can't not be called from any other file except sched_clock.c but same calculation( (cyc * mult) >> shift) can be done outside this file , In that case how do I calculate "shift" variable?

Comment: It's just an optimised [division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Division_by_a_constant). count / frequency = time

Answer (score 0):

The [clocksource](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/clocksource.h#L193) provides helper to calculate `mult` and `shift` values:

```
clocks_calc_mult_shift(u32 *mult, u32 *shift, u32 from, u32 to, u32 maxsec)
```

> @to and @from are frequency values in HZ. For clock sources @to is
>   NSEC_PER_SEC == 1GHz and @from is the counter frequency. For clock
>   event @to is the counter frequency and @from is NSEC_PER_SEC.
>
> The @maxsec conversion range argument controls the time frame in
>   seconds which must be covered by the runtime conversion with the
>   calculated mult and shift factors. This guarantees that no 64bit
>   overflow happens when the input value of the conversion is
>   multiplied with the calculated mult factor. Larger ranges may
>   reduce the conversion accuracy by chosing smaller mult and shift
>   factors.